# Return only array field in MongoDB document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection where each document has the following format:

```
    {
        "course_id": "course_id",
        "language": "language",
        "topics": [
            {
                "topic_id": "topic_id",
                "topic_title": "topic_title",
                "topic_description": "topic_description",
            },
        ],
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve, given a `course_id` and a `language`, an array (**and only the array, not a document with the `topics` field**) where each element has only the `topic_id` and `topic_title` fields, e.g.:

```
[
  {"topic_id": "id_1", "topic_title": "title1"},
  {"topic_id": "id_2", "topic_title": "title2"},
]
```

In order to retrieve **only the array** I used the [`.distinct()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#std-label-distinct-method-options) method as follows:

```
result = db.topics_collection.distinct("topics", {"course_id": course_id, "language": language})
```

Now I also need to filter out the `topic_description` field but the following query I tried did not work:

```
result = db.topics_collection.distinct("topics", {{"course_id": course_id, "language": language}, {"topic_description": 0}})
```

Is there another way (maybe also using a different method than `.distinct()`) to also filter out the `topic_description` field?

Comment: Will `"course_id"` and `"language"` specify a single document, or could there be multiple documents?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, there is only one document for each course_id - language pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method for this kind of thing:

```js
result = db.topics_collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      course_id: course_id,
      language: language
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$topics"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$topics"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic_id: 1,
      topic_title: 1
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kJN4NdoKbjS) for a working example.

Explanation:

1. `$match`: your query condition.
2. `$unwind`: the `$topics` array into separate documents.
3. `$replaceRoot`: of the document with the `$topics` object from each of these new documents.
4. `$project`: only the properties you want.

Comment: You could also [`"$project"` after the `"$match"`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zd03q-CHZxi "link to mongoplayground.net -->") to lighten the load a bit.

Comment: @rickhg12hs agreed that `$project` would reduce the size or the resulting unwound documents and I also like the `$replaceWith` - more modern and succinct than `$replaceRoot`.